# Skull of which animal ist it?

Tags: species-identification

Hi someone found this skull in ancient city of iran I'm just curious to find out which animal belongs this skull?[image]

Comment: Welcome - if you think that I have given the correct answer, use the check (tick) mark next to my answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 6):

This will be one of the two-toed ungulate mammals ([Artiodactyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artiodactyl)), I think one of the smaller ones, probably in the family [Bovidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovidae), which includes the antelopes and goats as well as cows and sheep.

Furthermore, because the laws of frequency tell us that it is rare to come across a rare species, therefore this is most likely to be a common species. So, what species are common in Iran, that have two horns curved gently towards the back of the skull?

Goat (*[Capra hircus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat)*) or sheep (*[Ovis aries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep)*) are the most likely animals, though I lean towards goats in this case because of the shape and position of the horns.

Comment: Having had many goats (of several breeds) and having to guard my rear around some of them, that was the first thing I thought of when I saw that partial skull.